# how can i fix this nginx in ubuntu16

Tags: nginx, ubuntu-16.04

I am newer to nginx and am getting this error message while

sudo apt-get install nginx

can any one help me to fix this

```
        nginx.service - A high performance web server and a reverse proxy server
    Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/nginx.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
    Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Mon 2017-08-28 15:12:09 IST; 20ms ago
    Docs: man:nginx(8)
    Process: 6656 ExecStartPre=/usr/sbin/nginx -t -q -g daemon on; master_process on; (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

    Aug 28 15:12:09 onlyoffice systemd[1]: Starting A high performance web serv.....
    Aug 28 15:12:09 onlyoffice nginx[6656]: nginx: [emerg] open() "/etc/nginx/ng...)
    Aug 28 15:12:09 onlyoffice nginx[6656]: nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx...d
    Aug 28 15:12:09 onlyoffice systemd[1]: nginx.service: Control process exite...=1
    Aug 28 15:12:09 onlyoffice systemd[1]: Failed to start A high performance w...r.
    Aug 28 15:12:09 onlyoffice systemd[1]: nginx.service: Unit entered failed state.
    Aug 28 15:12:09 onlyoffice systemd[1]: nginx.service: Failed with result 'e...'.
    Hint: Some lines were ellipsized, use -l to show in full.
    dpkg: error processing package nginx-full (--configure):
    subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
    dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of nginx:
    nginx depends on nginx-full (<< 1.13.3-0+xenial1.1~) | nginx-light (<< 1.13.3-0+xenial1.1~) | nginx-extras (<< 1.13.3-0+xenial1.1~); however:
    Package nginx-full is not configured yet.
    Package nginx-light is not installed.
    Package nginx-extras is not installed.
    nginx depends on nginx-full (>= 1.13.3-0+xenial1) | nginx-light (>= 1.13.3-0+xenial1) | nginx-extras (>= 1.13.3-0+xenial1); however:
    Package nginx-full is not configured yet.
    Package nginx-light is not installed.
    Package nginx-extras is not installed.

    dpkg: error processing package nginx (--configure):
    dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
    No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.
    Errors were encountered while processing:
    nginx-full
    nginx
    E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

thank you in advance

Comment: Well the error is right there:  `dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of nginx:
    nginx depends on nginx-full (<< 1.13.3-0+xenial1.1~) | nginx-light (<< 1.13.3-0+xenial1.1~) | nginx-extras (<< 1.13.3-0+xenial1.1~); however:
    `

Comment: @Stuart how can i fix this

Comment: Er - `Package nginx-full is not configured yet.
    Package nginx-light is not installed.
    Package nginx-extras is not installed.`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try to use the official nginx.repo for Ubuntu (Xenial)

Edit /etc/apt/sources.list and add these lines at the end of the file:

```
deb http://nginx.org/packages/ubuntu/ codename nginx
deb-src http://nginx.org/packages/ubuntu/ codename nginx
```

Save the file and run this commands:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install nginx
```

It should install the latest nginx version from the nginx official repo.

If that's not working try running this command instead:

```
apt-get -f install nginx

or

apt-get -f -y install nginx
```

Comment: Thank you for your quick response @Bogdan Stoica  actually  It's due to version problem  instead of latest version, I need last stable version

Comment: That will be the latest stable version as in their official repo... be sure that you have no other nginx version installed from other repos that might result into dependencies issues